# errors compare gives unexpected result

Tags: go

Today I found that `errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound)` gives me false. So I check...

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    ErrRecordNotFound := errors.New("record not found")
    myErr := errors.New("record not found")
    fmt.Println(errors.Is(myErr, ErrRecordNotFound)) // false
    fmt.Println(myErr == ErrRecordNotFound) // false
    fmt.Println(myErr.Error() == ErrRecordNotFound.Error()) // true
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/IDasF9AlJXb

Is it bug or I do something wrong?

UPDATE

Sorry for upper code.. The real code is

```
tx := db.Where("condition")
    err := tx.First(&pms).Error
    if errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
        return "unacceptable"
    }
```

but it doesn't work as expected

Comment: Every error created by errors.New is unique as documented: "Each call to New returns a distinct error value even if the text is identical." You are supposed to read the documentation of functions. This burden is bearable given that the documentation of errors.New is two sentences with a total of 25 words. The documentation of the stdlib is really good and should  be consulted first in any case.

Comment: Also consider reading [this](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/12/24/inspecting-errors).

Comment: Ok, my way to check was wrong. But maybe somebody can explain why Gorm expect to check error with errors.Is but it didn’t work?

Comment: @nobilik are you certain that the `err` is really `gorm.ErrRecordNotFound`? Can you share what the output of `fmt.Printf("%#v\n", err)` is?

Comment: @mkopriva here is it ```&errors.errorString{s:"record not found"}```

Comment: @nobilik it *seems* correct, try now printing the pointers of both, i.e. `fmt.Printf("%p\n", err)` and `fmt.Printf("%p\n", gorm.ErrRecordNotFound)`, do you get back the same address for both? If not, one explanation would be that you have multiple versions of gorm on your system, and the error returned by `tx.First(&pms).Error` is going to be from one version and the `gorm.ErrRecordNotFound` from another. Make sure the package of the latter is using the correct import path.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks a lot! There are two different versions.

Answer (score 3):

From `errors.Is`

> An error is considered to match a target if it is equal to that target
> or if it implements a method Is(error) bool such that Is(target)
> returns true.

The documentation for `errors.New` suggests that it creates distinct errors (even if text matches).

> `New` returns an error that formats as the given text. Each call to
> `New` returns a distinct error value even if the text is identical.

And there should be no expectation that any new error is equal to an error defined in an arbitrary package (such as `gorm`).

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I wasn't so good with my question. My problem is with GORM. Could you take a look to updated question?